# Why is resolvectl missing from CentOS 7

Tags: centos, dns, systemd-resolved

I've got a Linux system (Centos 7) on a LAN with about 70 Windows machines, but the Windows machine names are not in the DNS. I'm trying to use LLMNR (Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution) to resolve the IP addresses of the Windows machines, and from my research it looks like systemd-resolved is designed to do exactly that.

However, I'm having a hard time getting systemd-resolved working in CentOS 7. First of all, it isn't even installed with systemd; I had to install it separately. And even after I install the systemd-resolved package, there is no 'resolvectl' or 'resolvconf', so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to query it.

I'm concerned that I might be going about this the wrong way. Why isn't resolvectl in the systemd-resolved package for CentOS 7, and what am I supposed to use instead? Should I even be using systemd-resolved for this purpose in this Linux version, or is there different solution for using LLMNR?

Comment: Not an answer because I'm not entirely sure about this, but I think CentOS 7 predates `systemd-resolved` and friends. With CentOS 7 and distributions of similar vintage, I just use mDNS (as implemented by Avahi).